# SQL Server : case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case

I have table named `boolean` which contain 'true' and/or 'false' values as strings in one column.

I have problem to create `case` statement to show me whether there are only 'true' or 'false' or 'both' values

Example 1:

```
'true'  
'true'
```

result:'true'

Example 2:

```
'false'   
'false'  
'false'
```

Result: 'false'

Example 3:

```
'true'  
'false'  
'true'
```

Result: 'both'

Edit:

`case` statement should look like:

```
case 
   when  "column content are only true values"  then 'true' 
   when  "column content are only false values" then 'false'
   else 'both' 
end
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework task

Comment: I don't understand the described problem. Could you share the table's DDL, or better yet, an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: Take min and max value and compare them, if they differ -> both, otherwise take that value

Comment: Provide more information .. what you want to do

Comment: Also, keep in mind that sql server has a bit data type that is used for boolean values.

Comment: **Oh lord.** Did a teacher tell you to store boolean values as strings?

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** - not a flow-control statement. [See this other SO question and it's answer by ErikE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657536/mssql-stored-procedure-executing-different-queries-by-case#25657671) for a much more extensive explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could aggregate the `max` and `min` of the column, and then evaluate the results - if they are the same, there's only one value in the column. If not, there must be both. Note that since these are string representations the values are sorted lexicographically:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(col) = MIN(col) THEN MAX(col) ELSE 'both' END
FROM   my_table
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MIN(Col) <> MAX(Col) THEN 
          'Both'
       ELSE
          MIN(Col)
       END
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select case when count(distinct bool_column) = 2 then 'both'
            when sum(case when bool_column = 'false' then 1 end) > 0 then 'false'
            else 'true'
       end as result
from your_table
```

Comment: Works, but is complicated. I don't vote. But you could find a more elegant solution.